# Images wont show up in html

Tags: html, image

Hi im fairly new to html and have run into a problem when adding images from a local folder.

```
<img src="C:\ComputerBuild Pics\DSC_0037.NEF">
<img src="C:\ComputerBuild%Pics\DSC_0037.NEF">
<img src="ComputerBuild%2520Pics\DSC_0037.NEF">
<img src="ComputerBuild%Pics\DSC_0037.NEF">
```

Comment: maybe export them to `jpg` and try... [online converter](http://www.neftojpg.com/)

Answer (score 1):

NEF image file is raw image, compress this file https://raw.pics.io/convert-nef-to-jpeg

Answer (score 0):

A browser cannot render a NEF image file.
You need to convert it to a file format that a browser can interprete and render.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to supported images for web browsers.

On regards to that, there is this page in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support). See the chart for different images types and web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the images in .png format which stands for "Portable Network Graphics"

You can use this site to convert: http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-png

or you can use any graphics software of your choice